# Using ZOO-Project Ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, wps, server, zoo-project

I'm new with using servers but I've been using ubuntu for more than a year now. I've tried to install Zoo-project by following the instructions on the website : http://zoo-project.org/docs/install/debian.html. At first I tought that it was easy but when I try to reach the testing page : http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/zoo_loader.cgi?ServiceProvider=&metapath=&Service=WPS&Request=GetCapabilities&Version=1.0.0 I've an error message saying :

" This site can’t be reached

127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall "

I have the feeling that there is something I'm doing wrong. I don't know what... I've never started an server.

When I'm doing HTML, I start a server with python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 and I can see it in the port 8000 of 127.0.0.1 but when I try to use ZOO-project the instructions doesn't telling me how to start the server.

Do I need to install an apache server on my computer ? What is the step that I'm missing here ?

I don't know if I'm clear enough... I'm a GIS french guy after all lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you should have a HTTP Server and have defined the cgi-bin directory correctly for Apache (which is traditionally the case per default in most GNU/Linux distribution).

Comment: That was it. I've delete apache2 and his configuration and then reinstall it and I've run in the terminal
`code`
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
`code`

and now I can connect QGIS to my server. 
Thanks a lot ! Vous avez un vraiment beau projet !